# Dynamic Content Type? (field appears based on previous taxonomy choice)

Tags: entities, nodes

I want to show/hide a field based on a taxonomy choice (in the content admin side of things).

Though having this field attached to every item of this content type does add overhead; I suspect it contributes to the easiest solution for a dynamic field.

I like the idea of dynamic fields, where only certain instances of an entity would have/need them, however, this seems like it could be quite an undertaking. (or my Drupal imagination is lacking today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the [Conditional Fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module.

> Conditional Fields for Drupal 7 is an user interface to the new States API, plus the ability to modify fields appearance and behavior on certain conditions when viewing content.
>
> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the right condition.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I was imagining! Might have to warm up to contrib by working on this module...